# Семафор (теория)

Tags: c++

Представим у нас есть разделяемый буфер размером в 4 записи.

Есть два процесса:

1. делает запись в буфер (не может делать запись, когда уже есть 4
   записи)
2. читает из буфера ( не может читать из пустого буфера )

Можно ли с помощью семафора(ов) синхранизовать работу процессов так, чтобы работало корректно по условию, но не простым способом, где используется только одна ячейка буфера (записал-прочитал)?

Comment: Если взять 2 семафора (один на запись, один на чтение) со счётчиками (по числу записей в буфере), плюс отдельный счётчик записей, который надо будет изменять Interlocked функциями, то вполне можно сгородить требуемое. Только не понятно, зачем так переусложнять, если можно взять один мьютекс и сделать всё очевидным образом.

Comment: Но тут получается ещё один общий ресурс - счётчик записей. Первый процесс увеличивает, когда добавил запись, второй уменьшает, когда прочитал запись. А нам бы надо, чтобы буфер был единственным разделяемым ресурсом.